# How to run a method inside a Model when a JavaScript actionListener is triggered?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

I have the next Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '' )

    def process_likes(self):
        like = self.likes = F('likes')+1
        like.save()

    def split_tags(self):
        return self.tags.split()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What I want to do is when a icon in a template is clicked, I want the process_likes method to be run, this method is going to increment by one the value of likes.
My script looks like this:

```
<script>
    let corazon = document.querySelector('.icon-heart-empty');
    corazon.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        corazon.classList.toggle('icon-heart');
    });
</script>
```

Here I toggle the class of my icon to show if is clicked or uncliked, but how can I call the process_like method using pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an `AJAX` call to send a `POST` request to your server, and then return a response to your HTML page.

Example:

**view**

```
def process_like(request):
    post_id = request.POST['post_id']
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post.process_likes()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Success"})
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('process_like/', views.process_like, name="process_like")
    ...
]
```

**html/js**

```
<div class="post" data-post-id="{{post.id}}">this is the post</div>

<script>
var posts = document.querySelectorAll('.post')

posts.forEach(post => {
    post.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var post_id = post.getAttribute('data-post-id')
        var config = {
          method: "POST",
          body: {post_id: post_id}
          headers: {
              "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
        }

        fetch('{% url "process_like" %}', config)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    })
})
</script>
```

Or if you use jQuery

```
<script>
$('.post').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var post_id = $this.data('post-id');

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "{% url 'process_like' %}",
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", post_id: post_id}
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: is there a from of do this without jQuery?

Comment: @PaulMiranda I just updated my code to show an example of a vanilla JS version.

Comment: When I try this it shows me a error 403:Forbidden :( you know why this can be?

Comment: My bad! I updated the code to include the `csrf_token` necessary to bypass the 403 error. Try my updated JS code

Comment: I continue getting the 403 error, I'm thinking that maybe is something on the view method

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The issue is definitely `CSRF` related, since 403 errors are about authorization. I updated my code again for you, try it now.

Comment: The error 403 is gone but now I got a .MultiValueDictKeyError: 'post_id'. post_id is the default attribute my model get when is created, correct?

Comment: @PaulMiranda try replacing `body: {post_id: post_id}` with `body: JSON.stringify({post_id: post_id})`